# Cambiar el "setVisible" de un JLABEL desde otra clase en java, netbeams

Tags: java, netbeans, clase, interface, jlabel

Pues eso, tengo una clase con un label puesto tal que asi:

mainpanel.setVisible(true);

Pues el caso es que quiero que cuando le de ha un boton en otra clase ese setvisible sea false, aqui el evento del boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El label lo he creado con el diseñador de netbeans y lo tengo puesto como publico y estatico. Alguna idea?

Comment: pon tu imágen como código, no todo el mundo puede ver las imágenes

Comment: Porque no pone un metodo en la primera clase que cambie el setVisible( ) y luego instancia la primera clase desde la segunda llamando a dicho método?

Comment: He probado lo de instanciar pero no ha funcionado. Simplemente no hace nada.

Comment: Bien, si puedes editar tu pregunta para mostrar un ejemplo de como lo has intentado, es decir, mostrarnos las partes de tu codigo  que muestran los nombres e ambas clases, de quien extienden y la forma en que importas una clase en la otra e instancias